# Thunderbird shows passwords in cleartext by default

Tags: thunderbird

By default Thunderbird 115.6.0 shows the password in settings (Settings > Privacy & Security > Saved Passwords > Show Passwords).

I enabled the following config to ask for Windows password before showing the saved passwords:

*signon.management.page.os-auth.enabled*  **true**

Is that a secure way or are the passwords still saved as cleartext in some config files?

Answer (score 1):

No, `os-auth` only affects the button that shows *you* the password when you're opening the saved password list. It's an entirely voluntary prompt – notice that there is no such prompt when you *connect* to the mail server, even though Thunderbird needs to have the plaintext version of the password in order to connect.

Windows does have several ways Thunderbird could store passwords encrypted using your OS account (DPAPI, EFS) but they are all "quiet" (they just reuse the actual OS login password). Which means they only protect storage against theft externally, but not against malicious programs run under your own account. If that's suitable for you, you could go to Thunderbird's profile directory and enable "Encrypt this file" for key4.db (and perhaps for everything else too – it's not only your password that is stored; all of your mail messages are also cached on disk!).

There is a separate "Primary Password" or "Master Password" button in Thunderbird settings that enables encryption of your stored-password database using a separate password that you need to enter every time Thunderbird starts up. (Firefox has an identical feature.)

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is very good against the occasional visitor to your
computer, but there's no protection against a knowledgeable
person that has free access to the computer.

See the post
[How to read key3.db and logins.json in plain-text?](https://superuser.com/questions/1218631/how-to-read-key3-db-and-logins-json-in-plain-text),
where these above files are where passwords are stored.

The described methods in the post to retrieve all the passwords range
from using specialized utilities to installing password-exporting
extensions, but more methods than these surely exist.

Your best protection is to restrict the access to your computer.
If the computer is well-protected, the fact that Thunderbird
shows the passwords in clear-text is less of a problem.